# Creating a new column which is a vector of other columns

Tags: r, apply, lapply, dplyr

I have a dataframe with two columns (V1 and V2) and I'd like to create another column which is a vector - via combine function: c() - taking as arguments the other columns.

I'm using dplyr for all tasks, so I'd like to use it also in this context.

I've tried to create the new column with an apply function but it returns a vector with all the rows (not rowwise), something which surprises me, because with other functions it works rowwise.

I've solved it using the function rowwise, but as it's not usually so efficient, I'd like to see if there's another option.

Here is the definition of the dataframe:

```
IDs <- structure(list(V1 = c("1", "1", "6"),
                      V2 = c("6", "8", "8")),
                 class = "data.frame",
                 row.names = c(NA, -3L)
                 )
```

Here is the creation of the columns (together1 is the wrong result, and together2 the good one):

```
IDs <-
  IDs %>% 
  mutate(together1 = list(mapply(function (x,y) c(x,y), V1, V2))
        ) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(together2 = list(mapply(function (x,y) c(x,y), V1, V2))
        ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Here are the printed results:

```
print(as.data.frame(IDs))

V1 V2        together1 together2
1  1  6 1, 6, 1, 8, 6, 8      1, 6
2  1  8 1, 6, 1, 8, 6, 8      1, 8
3  6  8 1, 6, 1, 8, 6, 8      6, 8
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just missed the `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` in your `mapply()` call:

```
dplyr::mutate(IDs, togeher = mapply(c, V1, V2, SIMPLIFY = F))

  V1 V2 togeher
1  1  6    1, 6
2  1  8    1, 8
3  6  8    6, 8
```

Comment: Why does not sapply(V1, c, V2, simplify = FALSE) or lapply(V1, c, V2) work?

Comment: Try to think like an `lapply()` :) For each entry from `V1` it takes whole `V2` and concatenate them, like `c(V1[i], V2)` for all `i` from `1:length(V1)`.

Comment: Thanks, you're totally right. But another question: Why use SIMPLIFY = F? with mapply(c, V1, V2) you just calculate c(V1[i], V2[i])

Comment: Yes, but with  `SIMPLIFY = T` it returns `matrix`. If you try to run the same code with `SIMPLIFY = T`, it will through error `Column togeher must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 6`  which is probably because matrix is seen as a vector by `dplyr` .  I am not sure I understand what is going on under the hood in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation :)

Comment: For codegolfing, use  `Map`

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with `purrr`'s `map2` function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

IDs %>% 
  mutate(together = map2(V1, V2, ~c(.x, .y)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 4):

`pmap` could be used here

```
library(tidyverse)
IDs %>% 
   mutate(together = pmap(unname(.), c)) 
#  V1 V2 together
#1  1  6     1, 6
#2  1  8     1, 8
#3  6  8     6, 8
```